# The webkit-transition effect makes chrome 19 crash

Tags: google-chrome

After chrome stable version upgraded to 19, the simple html page make the browser crashed. I upload the page to a webserver, you can see the source code:

http://libragon.sinaapp.com/m/index.html

I found that the code `-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;` is the root cause. Why is this and how can I avoid it?